# saving cropped images in unique name?

Tags: php

This script helps me crop and save images. every time i save an image it saves has crop.jpg .. can i save it in a different name? i have an input field with image name.. "$_POST['imgname']" how can i use this has image name for the cropped image?

```
<?php
$canvasImg = $_POST['img'];    
$data = base64_decode($canvasImg);
$File = "captured.jpg"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $data);  
fclose($Handle);

$src_image = imagecreatefrompng($File);
$width = imagesx($src_image);
$height = imagesy($src_image);

$dst_x = 0;
$dst_y = 0;
$src_x = $width*0.350; // Crop Start X
$src_y = $height*0.165; // Crop Srart Y
$dst_w = $width*0.294; // Thumb width
$dst_h = $height*0.470; // Thumb height
$src_w = $dst_w; // $src_x + $dst_w
$src_h = $dst_h; // $src_y + $dst_h

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
imagealphablending($image, false);
$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,127);
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,$dst_w, $dst_h,$col);
imagealphablending($image,true);

imagecopyresampled($image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
imagealphablending($image,true);
imagealphablending($image,false);
imagesavealpha($image,true);
imagepng($image, "images/crop.jpeg");
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: `imagepng($image, "images/crop.jpeg");` change this. Hint: do not rely on copy-paste always.

Comment: you may rename it to time-stamp and save.

Comment: hi.. change it to what? n sry for copy-paste :)

Comment: @gumireddy something like this 
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");  
$new_name= date('ymd').time();
echo $new_name;
$extention = pathinfo('/path_to_old_file/file_name.extention'); //example pathinfo('images/image1.jpg');
 rename('/path_to_old_file/file_name.extention','/path_to_save_new_file/'.$new_name.$extention);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to make a new filename for the `imagepng()` to use.

This would seem a simple solution:

```
$canvasImg = $_POST['img'];    
$data = base64_decode($canvasImg);
$File = "captured.jpg"; 

...

// create a new filesname for the cropped image in $save_to
$save_to = 'images/';
$save_to .= str_replace(array('.jpg','.png'), '', $data ) // remove original extension if it existed
$save_to .= '_crop.jpg';
// use this new name to save the cropped image
imagepng($image, $save_to);
```

However your code does not seem to make much sence. You accept an image name in `$_POST['img']` then save it to a file called `capured.jpg` and then open it as a `.png` in `$src_image = imagecreatefrompng($File);`

I assume you must only be accepting `.png` files, and in that case why save it as a `.jpg`.

See what I mean, there appears to be a whole lot of confusion in your code.

Comment: hi bro im working a wordpress site.. i want to take an picture of the content.. i use html2canvas to get it done.. and im passing the post name has the image name $_POST['imgname']... so the cropped image can be saved in an unique name each time(postname).. "captured.jpg" takes a screen shot of the whole screen .. so then crops a part of the captured image to crop.jpg .. everything works fine with the code.. but the cropped image is replacing the crop.jpg everytime.. how do i save it with post name?

Comment: Like the example I posted!

Comment: im sorry bro.. it aint working for me.. im too bad in php :( im trying to understand and fix it..

Comment: Woops I forgot about the `images/` folder. I have changed the example code, have another look